# SVN checkout fails with "chunk delimiter was invalid" - what can be done?

Tags: linux, eclipse, svn, version-control

In the middle of the checkout (`http://aima-java.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/`), the client stops with an error, the exact error message reads:

`org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn:REPORT of '/svn/svn/vcc/default': Chunk delimiter was invalid`

I have googled the error but was unable to find a solution. The only thing I am now aware of is that the issue is somehow caused by incompatible svn versions.

I use svn **1.6.12** from the regular ubuntu repo. The error is reproducible with multiple clients (tested with Eclipse and RabbitVCS) as they all use the same backend.

Any suggestions as to how to deal with this isssue and to avoid it in the future?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look to this bug :
http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2647

You may try to **update/checkout in small chunk**, folder by fodler maybe.

Comment: Thanks, so it was not a version issue after all, but the svn unable to cope with a bad internet connection. managed to checkout in tiny pieces after all but it was not pretty :)

Comment: Bad network connection, too many packet loss, etc. It's good that your issue is now solved.

Comment: Yes, probably a bad network connection, I got the same error and it worked after three attempts the third time.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this problem by turning off the wireless connection and using only a wired connection to make a large checkout.  After doing that the problem went away.

For incremental checkouts we don't get the error on wireless or wired.