# "Chunk delimiter was invalid" or "Could not read chunk size" on Visual SvnServer

Tags: svn, visualsvn-server, svnserve

**ERRORS**

When checking out a large project we receive error on a random file in the project:

> Could not read chunk size: connection was closed by server

or

> Chunk delimiter was invalid

the problem occurs randomly. Most of the time everything works.

**SETTING**

Svnserver run on port 80, with this custom setting in `C:\Program Files (x86)\VisualSVN Server\conf\httpd-custom.conf`

```
SVNInMemoryCacheSize 1000000

<Location /svn/>
  SVNCacheTextDeltas on
  SVNCacheFullTexts on
  SVNCacheRevProps on
</Location>
```

**COMPONENTS**

- Windows 2008 Server R2
- VisualSVN 3.2.2
- Apache Subversion 1.8.11
- Apache HTTP Server 2.2.29

**DETAILS**

Project is very large, more or less 200 files and over 500 mega bytes

*Anyone aware of this issue and how to resolve it?*

Comment: Have you tried any of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12936148/svn-checkout-fails-with-chunk-delimiter-was-invalid

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7808308/svn-checkout-fails-with-chunk-delimiter-was-invalid-what-can-be-done

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772894/updating-from-svn-repository-returns-could-not-read-chunk-size-error

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7882388/svn-check-out-has-issue-could-not-read-chunk-size

Comment: yes... no solution found

Answer (score 2):

Do you have any out of memory/crash events in event log?

I suggest you upgrade to VisualSVN Server 3.3.0 due the following change:

> - Fixed: unbounded server side memory usage is possible under some
>     circumstances.
>     https://www.visualsvn.com/server/changes/#v3.3.0

I also would like to note that you configured VisualSVN Server to use 1 GB for internal caches: do you really need this? Do you have another RAM on your server for such big cache?

Btw 200 files and 500 MB is pretty small project size for Subversion.

Comment: `Do you have any out of memory/crash events in event log?` I don't have this problem. After some tests, it seems due by antivirus (Nod32, kaspersky). Disabling web filters, everything works.